# Automate the calculation in Python of a Distribution Function in a system of equations

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scikit-learn, scipy

I would like to calculate an approximation of the data [Distribution Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function) in a `system of equations`:

```
F(t) := P(X <= t) ~ sum_i_frequency(observation_i <=t) / total_observation =: f(t)
```

My data:

```
List_Goals: [1, 2, 2, 1, 2]  
Matches played: 5
```

For example, if a football club, in the last 5 matches, scores [1, 2, 2, 1, 2], it means that:

```
- 0 goals, scored 0 times (nothing);
- 1 or less goals, scored 2 times (1, 1);
- 2 or fewer goals, scored 5 times (1, 2, 2, 1, 2);

If the goals scored are <= 0 events, then i will have 0/5 = 0;
If the goals scored are <= 1 events, then I will have 2/5 = 0.4;
If the goals scored are <= 2 events, then I will have 5/5 = 1;

f(0) = 0/5 = 0;
f(1) = 2/5= 0.4;
f(2) = 5/5= 1;

System: {f(0) = F(0) } therefore 0/5= 0
        {f(1) = F(1) } therefore 2/5= 0.4
        {f(2) = F(2) } therefore 5/5= 1
```

In this case i have three equations in one unknown, but obviously the system must be set up with a number of equations ranging from `F(0)` to `F(max_goals_scored)`. This way I would have `max_goals_scored + 1 equations`. I should therefore start the solution starting from the `max_goals_scored+1 equations` and increase, for example, if I had a number 6 in List_Goals (List_Goals: [1, 2, 6, 1, 2], the functions would be with a maximum of 6: `F(0), F(1), F(2), F(3), F(4), F(5), F(6)`

How can I automate everything in Python? I accept any library

Comment: This is not correct. `f(2) != F(2)` while `F(2) = 1` `f(2) =0.6`. Consider having the correct output

Comment: A quick search should help you note that the The pmf is different from cdf.  pmf is for probability at that particular point. eg `P(X == x)` while the cdf is the probability of atmost x. ie `P(X <=x)` these two would yield different results

Comment: eg, for PMF, `(np.array(Goals)==0).mean(); (np.array(Goals)==1).mean(); (np.array(Goals)==2).mean()` while for CDF we have `(np.array(Goals)<=0).mean(); (np.array(Goals)<=1).mean(); (np.array(Goals)<=2).mean()` I hope this helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `bincount`:

```
import numpy as np
Goals = [1, 2, 2, 1, 2] 
f = np.bincount(Goals)/len(Goals)
f
array([0. , 0.4, 0.6])

F = f.cumsum()
array([0. , 0.4, 1. ])
```

Note that `f` is the probability mass function while `F` is the cummulative mass function. The two are not the same

Comment: I get error: NameError: name 'res' is not defined

Comment: @Tappetinoorange sorry about that. it should be `f` not res. fixed it

Comment: This answer has the nice property that it makes no assumptions about what distribution the data is coming from. It has the slightly weird effect that it assigns zero probability to 3 goals, but you could fix that by having more data. I think this answer is the best that can be done without making an assumption about the distribution it's coming from, e.g. poisson or negative binomial.

Comment: @Onyambu A little curiosity: why is there a point after the 0, but there is nothing else after the point? If it's just 0, shouldn't it be 0 with no point?

Comment: @Tappetinoorange thats just a way for python to indicate floats. ie show that the valuesare not integers. its all about data types.

Comment: @NickODell  What do you mean by ". It has the slightly weird effect that it assigns zero probability to 3 goals"? Is it a problem? Can you explain yourself better? Thank you

Comment: @Tappetinoorange If I offered a bet where I bet $1 against your $100 that the next soccer game would have 3 goals, would you take it? If you believe this distribution, which assigns a probability of 0 to this event, then this is a good bet, since 0 is smaller than 0.01.

Comment: @NickODell note that the solution provided deals with the data given. For example, the solution indicates the probability of having 0 goals as 0. The problem is not with the implementation but rather with the way OP phrased the question. This solution is adequately sufficient to the problem asked. If there should be some probability for 0,3,4..goals, that should be tacked by OP and not by the provided solution

Comment: @NickODell Sorry, but I didn't understand your example. Could you explain it to me in a more technical way please? Shouldn't the probability of 3 goals be 0 in your opinion?

Comment: @Onyambu I understand, now I understand. Sorry, I didn't see your comment above. However, for the moment your code is more than sufficient. A thousand thanks. I already voted on your question yesterday, now I have accepted it